# Failed to "push origin master"

Tags: git, github

Im trying to commit my files to GitHub.
My commands :

```
git status
git add -A
git commit -m 'message'
git push master origin
```

Then these errors showed up

```
error: src refspec origin does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'master'
```

What should I do to fix this ?
Thank you.

Comment: `git push [repository] [refspec]`, you have it the other way round, try `git push origin master`. in other words, you're trying to push to repository `master` a branch named `origin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `git push master origin`...please try the following command:

`git push origin master`